# Import GLTF Tilt Brush via Google Poly is throwing an error

Tags: import, gltf

Blender Version 2.90.1 (2.90.1 2020-09-23)

I have made a very simple Tilt Brush drawing on Oculus Quest 2. I have exported it to Poly from Tilt Brush. In Poly I have published the sketch in private mode. I am then fetching a link to it via the Poly API, and download a GLTF fil (https://poly.googleapis.com/downloads/fp/1602791954433581/7xSV2Yv6hW6/6eSd6Co6PZC/sketch.gltf). When I try to import that file (standard import settings), I get the following error from Blender:

```
    File "/Applications/Blender.app/Contents/Resources/2.90/scripts/addons/io_scene_gltf2/io/com/gltf2_io.py", line 46, in from_union
    return f(x)
  File "/Applications/Blender.app/Contents/Resources/2.90/scripts/addons/io_scene_gltf2/io/com/gltf2_io.py", line 1162, in <lambda>
    accessors = from_union([lambda x: from_list(Accessor.from_dict, x), from_none], obj.get("accessors"))
  File "/Applications/Blender.app/Contents/Resources/2.90/scripts/addons/io_scene_gltf2/io/com/gltf2_io.py", line 70, in from_list
    assert isinstance(x, list)
08:11:20 | ERROR: An error occurred on line 46 in statement return f(x)
08:11:20 | ERROR: An error occurred on line 1162 in statement accessors = from_union([lambda x: from_list(Accessor.from_dict, x), from_none], obj.get("accessors"))
08:11:20 | ERROR: An error occurred on line 70 in statement assert isinstance(x, list)
  File "/Applications/Blender.app/Contents/Resources/2.90/scripts/addons/io_scene_gltf2/io/com/gltf2_io.py", line 46, in from_union
    return f(x)
  File "/Applications/Blender.app/Contents/Resources/2.90/scripts/addons/io_scene_gltf2/io/com/gltf2_io.py", line 38, in from_none
    assert x is None
08:11:20 | ERROR: An error occurred on line 46 in statement return f(x)
08:11:20 | ERROR: An error occurred on line 38 in statement assert x is None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/Blender.app/Contents/Resources/2.90/scripts/addons/io_scene_gltf2/__init__.py", line 928, in execute
    return self.import_gltf2(context)
  File "/Applications/Blender.app/Contents/Resources/2.90/scripts/addons/io_scene_gltf2/__init__.py", line 942, in import_gltf2
    if self.unit_import(path, import_settings) == {'FINISHED'}:
  File "/Applications/Blender.app/Contents/Resources/2.90/scripts/addons/io_scene_gltf2/__init__.py", line 955, in unit_import
    success, txt = self.gltf_importer.read()
  File "/Applications/Blender.app/Contents/Resources/2.90/scripts/addons/io_scene_gltf2/io/imp/gltf2_io_gltf.py", line 164, in read
    self.data = gltf_from_dict(json.loads(content, parse_constant=glTFImporter.bad_json_value))
  File "/Applications/Blender.app/Contents/Resources/2.90/scripts/addons/io_scene_gltf2/io/com/gltf2_io.py", line 1218, in gltf_from_dict
    return Gltf.from_dict(s)
  File "/Applications/Blender.app/Contents/Resources/2.90/scripts/addons/io_scene_gltf2/io/com/gltf2_io.py", line 1162, in from_dict
    accessors = from_union([lambda x: from_list(Accessor.from_dict, x), from_none], obj.get("accessors"))
  File "/Applications/Blender.app/Contents/Resources/2.90/scripts/addons/io_scene_gltf2/io/com/gltf2_io.py", line 56, in from_union
    assert False
AssertionError
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the problem is, that Poly exports GLTF v1.0, which is unsupported by Blender and others (ThreeJS, Chronos Blender GLTF Importer)

Comment: Thanks.  We're adding a more helpful error message to the glTF importer in Blender 2.91.  https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-IO/pull/1238